# I will try my level best

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, indian-english

> **I will try my level best**.

I have heard this expressions from many Indian speakers of English.

Is it not enough if we say:

> **I wil try my best**

Is try **one's level best** a set phrase? what is the use of **level**  in the sentence? Is it Indianism or standard English usage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the full (subscription-only) [Oxford English Dictiomnary...](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/107654?redirectedFrom=level%20best#eid39373083)

> **one's level best**
>    one's very best; the utmost one can possibly do. Also **levelest** in the same sense, and similarly **level worst**, etc. colloquial or slang (originally U.S.).
>   Of these only **level best** is standard in the U.K.
>
> First citation 1851 (An Arkansaw Doctor): *We put our horses out at their level best.*

It's not immediately obvious to me as a native speaker how this sense arose from the original *flat horizontal surface / vertical displacement.* Perhaps it's an allusion to being at the ***top level*** (which must be at some given "height", so if it's also "flat", there's no way to go any further ***up***).

OR - given that the first citation is from a *horse-racing* context, perhaps the allusion is to [***flat-racing***](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/flat-racing) (a type of racing where the horses do not jump over fences, which implies ***maximum speed***).